# My MySQL query with Count/Group By doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm writing a PM (private messages) system in PHP for one of my projects, and I'm stuck with a single MySQL query that uses (or should be using) Count. The query would take place in a function, which is supposed to return the value of unread messages for `$id` user.

My table layout looks like this:

```
___________________________________________________________________________________
+-message_id--||--from_user--||--to_user--||--content--||--date_sent--||--is_read-+
```

And I wrote a query like that:

```
$count = mysql_query("
    SELECT Count(from_user) 
    FROM messages 
    WHERE to_user='$id' 
    AND is_read=0 
    GROUP BY to_user
",$connection);
```

I'm not really familiar with this Count/Group By stuff, so I'm not sure about what I did wrong. I did a few Google searches, but didn't find anything which could be useful for me.

If you could help me about this little problem, that would be awesome.

Thanks! :)

Comment: What do you get and what do you expect to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    messages
WHERE   to_user = '$id'
        AND is_read = 0
```